# Удаление в бинарном файле, Си

Tags: c

Данная таблица хранится в бинарном файле. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно удалить одну их этих записей. Пускай будем задавать номер записи, которую удаляем. Не понимаю, как поставить указатели в нужное место.
Запись в файл осуществляется последовательным дополнением элементов, порядок как номера в таблице и как последовательность полей

```
void Addition() {


    if (N == 49) {
        printf("Массив заполнен\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("\nВведите номер рейса:");
        scanf_s("%d", &One.number);
        getchar();
        printf("\nВведите аэропорт назначения:");
        gets(&One.airname, 20);
        getchar();
        printf("\nВведите название авиакомпании:");
        gets(&One.airline, 20);
        getchar();
        printf("\nВведите тип самолета:");
        gets(&One.crafttype, 20);
        printf("\nВведите время прибытия по расписанию:");
        scanf_s("%d", &One.tabletime);
        printf("\nВведите ожидаемое время прибытия:");
        scanf_s("%d", &One.exptime);
        printf("\nВведите количество пассажиров:");
        scanf_s("%d", &One.amount);
        N++;
    }

    FILE *BD;

    if ((BD = fopen("BD.bin", "a+b")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Невозможно открыть для записи файл 'task1.dta'\n");
        return;
    }

    fwrite(&One.number, sizeof(int), 1, BD);
    fwrite(&One.airname, sizeof(char), 20, BD);
    fwrite(&One.airline, sizeof(char), 20, BD);
    fwrite(&One.crafttype, sizeof(char), 20, BD);
    fwrite(&One.tabletime, sizeof(int), 1, BD);
    fwrite(&One.exptime, sizeof(int), 1, BD);
    fwrite(&One.amount, sizeof(int), 1, BD);

    fclose(BD);

    N++;
}
```

Comment: Смотря в каком порядке записываются данные. Можете привести код, который записывает эту таблицу в файл? Или каким образом эта таблица считывается из файла.

Comment: Запись идет в том же порядке, как и номера в таблице

Comment: То есть сначала записывается №1 `Номер рейса`, потом `Аэропорт назначения`, и т.д., затем тоже самое для №2?

Comment: Бинарные файлы разные бывают. У вас фиксированная длина записи или переменная ? Если первое, то `fseek(номер_записи*длина_записи)` (нумерация записей с 0). А вот если второе то конечно ее придется искать с самого начала файла, если заранее не сохранить где она находится

Comment: @Andrei Khotko да

Comment: @Mike
Записи чего? Строки фиксированные,
сам файл никак не ограничиваю

Comment: @Александр Вы в вопросе пишите "_Мне нужно удалить одну их этих записей_". Вот у меня слово "запись", означает ровно то же, что в этой вашей фразе

Comment: @Mike Извините, не понял сразу. Запись формируется из переменных инт и фиксированных строк. Получается что да, записи тоже фиксированной длины

Comment: Записи у вас одной длины... берите последнюю запись и перезаписывайте на место нужной, а сам файл обрезайте. Или помечайте запись как удаленную, а время от времени перезаписывайте все неудаленные записи из одного файла в другой, с последующим переименованием фaйла.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо!